# Intent issue (display new form) Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Ok I've been looking around for hours.  I've tried just about everything and I'm not sure what is going on but I'm getting the issue where it can't find the activity.  The activity is in my manifest file.  I've tried with .ActivityName and com...ActivityName.  I've saved, I've cleaned, I've closed/opened eclipse.  It just can't seem to find it.  Here's code, maybe I'm missing something?

Manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
```

Listener in MainActivity:

```
View.OnClickListener test = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
ImageButton btnTest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btnTest= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnDepressed);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(GoTest);
}
...etc.
```

I've read so many articles on this from here and other sites.  I've watched videos.. I simply don't see what I'm doing wrong.  The activity is defined in the manifest, I've tried the intent with the above code, as well as with:

```
new Intent("com.blah.blah.Activity2");
```

Neither is working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post crash log?

Comment: Please edit the question and include the manifest.

Comment: What do you whant to do ? Go to another acivity ? You need a context in your intent : new Intent(context, Activity2.class).

Comment: @Tsunaze, er, the OP has one - `MainActivity.this`, which is the general pattern for referencing an Activity context in an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   <activity android:name=".Activity2"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blah.blah.Activity2" />
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

from activity code you have to do some thing like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.blah.blah.Activity2");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);`
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Upvoted.  I saw that the main activity was defined this way, but none of the posts/forums I looked at mentioned to do this for secondary/tertiary/etc activities.  They just said to do it the "activity android:name=".ActivityName"></activity> way.  As soon as I used this code - done.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your package com.blah.blah for Activity2. 
Inside your AndroidManifest.xml you should define your package as:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blah.blah"
...
```

And define your activity as:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.blah.blah.Activity2">
    </activity>
```

OR

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2">
    </activity>
```